# Resolving package dependencies offline

Tags: dependencies, package, redhat, rpm

I have RedHat v.6.2 server without internet access. I have install it yesterday, but it hasn't vncserver., I want to install vnc. I have `yum` and `rpm`. VNC requires a few packages and libraries, but these libs requires more and more etc.

I decide to do following:

1. Find **all** dependences of `vncserver` recursively
2. Find and exclude from this list already installed packages
3. Download to other machine or to usb drive all required packages
4. Install it on target machine like from local repository

Can you give me a hint about `1` and `2`? May be you know other solution or you have faced with the same situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use yum in a download only mode on the other machine, in order to get all required RPMs